# Internet Download Manager Extension Not working in Comodo Dragon ( Google Chrome)

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

The extension for Internet Download Manager has stopped working in Google Chrome.

Everything was working alright until I updated IDM to 6.19.2, then the extension for Comodo Dragon stopped working suddenly. Other extensions are still working fine.

Has anybody encountered something like this?

Things I tried doing:

1. Uninstalling and reinstalling
2. Updating the extension (last update is 6.19.2)
3. Checking Base Filter Engine Service. according to IDM website : http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/register/new_faq/enableBFE.html